# Have small chat application but i need current online users

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

In sharepoint I do have chatter web part.

That web part does not show the online user.

In sharepoint are there any ways to get online users into the WEB PART.

Please guide it is the requirement.

THanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box with SharePoint.  It's a big limitation, I know because I've been looking for ways to do this as well.  But there may be a ways around it:

The following was proposed here: go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/code-get-many-users-logged-sharepoint-79841.aspx

What comes to mind is that you could write something that would hook into the session_start and session_end.  Here's an ASP.NET blog that covers it.  http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocID.aspx?QUICKDOC=223.

I then realized that this may not work since sharepoint  uses SqlServer, by default, not InProc for its session mgmt.  This would prevent session_end from firing.

Ok, so if you change your web.config to use InProc, it should work.  There are implications in doing this, of course.  Here is an article that lets you assess where this is a safe thing to do based on your environment.  http://sharepoint-one-stop.blogspot.com/2008/06/moss-2007-interview-questions.html